# How add svg overlay to google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, svg

I want create some like this http://svo.aero/transport/ with google map api, add svg overlay to map and when mouse on some object show information. But i can't find some examples or information how add svg overlay to google map

Answer (score 3):

Well, that isn't google maps. It looks more like OpenLayers (it says yandex maps, I don't know if it has any relationship with other lib). As per overlaying an SVG image, you can do it with an [OverlayView object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#OverlayView).

Basically you would instance an OverlayView. To do this, the basic skeleton is to implement `onAdd`, `draw` and `onRemove` methods:

```
var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
myoverlay.draw = function () {
  // this will be executed whenever you change zoom level
};

myoverlay.onRemove = function () {
  // this will be executed whenever you call setMap(null) on this overlay
};

myoverlay.onAdd = function () {
  // this will be executed when you call setMap(your map) on this object
};

myoverlay.setMap(map);
```

That last step will trigger onAdd and draw. Since draw will execute repeatedly during your map lifecycle, you'd want to use de onAdd method to put your SVG inclusion code (otherwise, you'd end up with several SVG spawning without control)

```
myoverlay.onAdd = function () {
    // let's get a reference to the markerLayer mapPane, which will contain your SVG
    var panes = this.getPanes();

    // create a div and append it to the markerLayer pane        
    var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
    panes.markerLayer.appendChild(mydiv);

    // create an SVG element and append it to your div
    var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    var mysvg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'svg');
    mysvg.setAttribute('width', "100%");
    mysvg.setAttribute('height', "100%");
    ...whatever other attributes you want to add..
    ...whatever other child elements you want to append to your svg element
    mydiv.appendChild(mysvg);

};
```

That's it. Since the SVG was added inside an OverlayView, it will retain its original size and position, so you can pane and zoom freely without the svg moving around or scaling unrelated to the map.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what technology/CMS you use. If you have a WordPress website then check out [MapSVG](http://mapsvg.com) - it can do exactly what you need. You can take any SVG file, overlay it on Google Map and make it clickable.